# Значення слова "тягне" в пісні "Іди сину пріч од мене"

Tags: значення-слів

> [Іди , сину , пріч од мене](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFhwFRN-IsY) (YouTube)
>
> Іди, сину, пріч од мене,
>   Ой, не хочу, рідна нене,
>   Пріч од мене, неслухняне,
>   Нехай тебе Горда **тягне**,
>   Нехай тебе Горда **тягне**.
>
> Мене, мамо, Горда знає,
>   В чистім полі ображає,
>   Дуже добре Горда знає,
>   В чистім полі ображає,
>   В чистім полі ображає.
>
> Іди, сину, пріч од мене,
>   Ой, не хочу, рідна нене,
>   Пріч од мене, неслухняне,
>   Нехай тебе шляхта **тягне**,
>   Нехай тебе шляхта **тягне**.

Я не можу зрозуміти значення слова **тягне** в цій пісні. "Тягнути насильно, як раба"? "Захопити за собою, як рiвноправну людини"? Або **тягне** вдалину, як мрія чи амбіції?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мою думку, це щось на зразок *утримувати когось*, *тягти на собі*.

Син жив коло матері, яка його утримувала. В передостанньому куплеті пісні син вирішив сам себе забезпечувати:

> Та вже ж піду щось робити,
> На лиманах буду жити,
> По звичаю буду жити:
> Сіль по-старому возити,
> Та й на щуку ніж гострити.

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/tjaghty) подає також такі значення:

> **ТЯГТИ** і **ТЯГНУТИ**, тягну, тягнеш; *мин. ч.* тяг, ла, ло; тягнув, нула, ло; *недок.*
>
> // за ким, *перен., розм.* Підтримувати кого-небудь, бути на чийомусь боці, діяти в чиїх-небудь інтересах. *Батько все тягне за Романком — своїм пестунчиком* (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 102).
>
> 15. *перех., перен., розм.* Віддаючи багато сил, наполегливо працюючи, долаючи труднощі, вести що-небудь (господарство, якусь ділянку роботи). *[Горленко:] Вони [жінки] тут без нас усе господарство тягнули стільки років. Мабуть, потомились. Хоч у мене рука ще не зовсім в порядку, а я вирішив — завтра ж сідаю на трактор* (Олександр Корнійчук, II, 1955, 91); *— Сам один на своєму горбі всю газету тягну* (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 552).

Comment: Дякуємо! А яке значення у слова "Горда"? Це якась жінка?

Comment: @CopperKettle, цікаве питання. Мене навіть це цікавить більше за «тягне». Здається, я знаю, відповідь про «горду» (і вона перекреслює цю відповідь про «тягне»), але поки що не маю часу написати.

Comment: пройшло стільки часу, не тримайте так довго інтригу, скажіть про свої думки на рахунок "Горда" ;)

Comment: @ІгорНич, так сталося, що я вже забув, що мав тоді на думці (можливо — саме те, що Ви написали у [своїй відповіді](/a/6326), а можливо — і щось інше).

Answer (score 4):

Якщо змінити трішки слова, а саме

> Мене, мамо, **орда** знає,
> В чистім полі об'їжджає,
> Дуже добре **орда** знає,
> В чистім полі об'їжджає..

все стає відразу зрозуміліше, наш слух інколи нас підводить ;)

**Оновлено:**
[Текст пісні у Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD,_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD,_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD,_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96), у якій сина мають тягнути ляхи, турчин, москаль. Відповідно замість "Горда" там згадується "орда", що цілком природно вписується у цей ряд козацьких ворогів.

Comment: Мені здається це найвірогіднішою версією. (Не пам'ятаю, про що я думав у квітні 2018, коли писав [«здається, я знаю, відповідь про «горду» (і вона перекреслює цю відповідь про „тягне“)»](/q/3850#comment6654_3852), але не виключено, що саме про це).

Comment: Цїлком можливо, позаяк протеза можлива і декотрі Словянські мови писють таке слово через **h**: _слн_ hórda, _слц_, _пол_, _ч_ horda.